# indentation in Koma-script table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, indentation

I would like to indent  the chapter lines of the table of contents (it includes parts and chapters) but apparently I am not able to do it.

I understand that the Koma-script I am using (scrbook) should do it by default, but it doesn't. I have been reading the manual and several forum questions about it. Apparently a toc=graduated or toc=indent options can be used. I tried to put the option in the documentclass but it does not work.

Could anybody help me?

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing


\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
%\setkomafont{element}{commands}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
}


\begin{document}
\author{}

\subject{Linea Guida}
\title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
\subtitle{}
\titlehead{}


\date{Gennaio 2022}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}



\mainmatter
\part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\part{Quesiti}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: make an example that we can actually compile to see the issue. So remove all these \include and add a few chapters manually.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I edited the code in the original message eliminating all the "include"; I left the first part unchanged. I hope that it works as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each sectioning command has a so called `depth`, e.g. -1 for `\part`, 0 for `\chapter`, 1 for `\section` and so on. Indentation starts only with `\section`. Since you have only defined `\chapter`, none of your entries in indented.

Adding a few additional levels yield the expected result

[image: TOC with indentation]

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing


\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
%\setkomafont{element}{commands}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
}


\begin{document}
    \author{}
    
    \subject{Linea Guida}
    \title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
    \subtitle{}
    \titlehead{}
    
    
    \date{Gennaio 2022}
    
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Intro}
    
    
    
    \mainmatter
    \part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
    \chapter{one (depth=0)}
    \section{First section (depth=1)}
    \subsection{A subsection (depth=2)}
    % The subsubsection does not appear in the toc, because the default is tocdepth=2 for scrbook
    \subsubsection{And a subsubsection (depth=3)}
    \section{Second section}
    \chapter{two}
    \part{Quesiti}
    \chapter{three}
    \chapter{four}
    \backmatter
    % bibliography, glossary and index would go here.
    
\end{document}
```

The `\section` and `\subsection` and unnumbered, because you specified `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`, meaning only `\part` and `\chapter` are numbered.

Also, notice that the `\subsubsection` does not appear in the table of contents. This is controlled via the counter `tocdepth` which has a default value of `2` for the `scrbook` class.

Koma-Script has some handy commands, so you don't have to remember the different depths. Adding `\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}` would include `\subsubsection` in the table of contents.

If you would like to have your chapters `one`, `two` and so on indented, you can add this to your preamble.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocindent=2em
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocindent=4em
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocindent=6em
]{subsection}
```

[image: TOC with chapter indent]

Comment: Great!I found out another solution: `\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}%remove indent for section
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{30pt}% add indent for \subsection
% \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsubsection` but your solution seems far more linear